# Partitioning an integer into $k$ equal parts

Tags: combinatorics, partitions

Say I have an integer $M$. Is there a one-line command to create a partition of $M$ into $k$ integers s.t. the difference between any two integers is as small as possible?

For example, with $M = 100$ and $k = 10$, we would create the partition: {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10}.  However, for $k = 7$, we might have the partition: {14,14,14,14,14,14,16}, or better {14,14,14,14,14,15,15}.

For a partial solution, you can of course write:

```
M = 100;
k = 7;
BalancedPartition = Array[Floor[M/k] &, k];
BalancedPartition[[k]] += M - k*Floor[M/k];
BalancedPartition
```

> {14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 16}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not know single command to do this (it does not imply it does not exist:)). But it is two-line command:

```
dec[val_, par_] :=With[{ip = IntegerPart[val/par], md = Mod[val, par]}, 
                       ConstantArray[ip, par-md]~Join~ConstantArray[ip+1, md]]

dec[100, 10]
```

> {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}

```
dec[100, 7]
```

> {14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15}

This is straightforward method: for `k`-integer components `md=Mod[val,k] ε [0, k-1]` so it is adding `1` to `md` last positions of final list.

One could use `Quotient[val,par]` or `Floor[val/par]` insted of `IntegerPart`.

**Edit.** Also:

> ConstantArray in place of Table will make this faster. – Michael E2

So I swapped them.

Comment: (+1). `ConstantArray` in place of `Table` will make this faster.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 11):

I like the idea of using `IntegerPartitions` as that is after all what we are doing.  We can use it much more efficiently than Jonathan's answer by restricting the set of integers from which the elements are chosen using the third parameter.

```
f[m_, k_] := First @ IntegerPartitions[m, {k}, {0,1} + ⌊m/k⌋]

f[100, 7]
```

> ```
> {15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14}
> ```

As a fan of terse code I also quite like this fractional carry method using `FoldList`:

EDIT: I forgot I was using [my customized `FoldList` syntax.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433867/618728).  The code below will require it.

EDIT 2: my customized `FoldList` syntax [has been made standard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121), though undocumented.  Hurrah!

```
f2[m_, k_] := ⌊FoldList[## - ⌊#⌋ &, Table[m/k, {k}]]⌋

f2[100, 7]
```

> ```
>  {14, 14, 14, 15, 14, 14, 15}
> ```

(Note: `## - ⌊#⌋` is a "clever" way to write `# + #2 - ⌊#⌋`.)

Or taking a different approach:

```
f2[m_, k_] := ⌊FoldList[# - ⌊#⌋ + m/k &, m/k, Range[k-1]]⌋
```

Answer (score 5):

We need a function that produces a list of `k` elements equal to `Quotient[m,k]`, and then increments `Mod[m,k]` of them by 1.  This seems to be the rationale underlying Kuba's answer ,by the way.

That can be represented by:

```
   f[m_, k_] := Table[Quotient[m, k], {k}] + PadLeft[Table[1, {Mod[m, k]}], k]
```

You can retrieve  `Quotient` and `Mod` from the function `QuotientRemainder`. The code is a tad longer, but it shows that the key work is being done by a single function.

```
   f[m_, k_] := Table[#, {k}] + PadLeft[Table[1, {#2}], k] & @@ QuotientRemainder[m, k]
```

**Testing**

```
f[100, #] & /@ Range[29] // Column
```

[image: table]

Comment: It is the same idea but the shorter the better :) +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use `IntegerPartition` and set up the following:

```
With[{x = IntegerPartitions[100, {7}]},With[{y = Max[#] - Min[#] & /@ x}, 
x[[Position[y, Min[y]] // Flatten]]]]
```

This will take the difference between the max and min values and take those partitions which have the minimum value for that.

Comment: this will be rather slow for "large" `n`...?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it would be.

Comment: +1 for inspiration.  FWIW this can be made much faster (see my answer).

Comment: ah, I wasn't really aware of the third argument of `IntegerPartions`, thanks for pointing that out, @Mr.Wizard!

Answer (score 4):

An approximate table of k lots of M/k rounded down plus a correction.  O(k) in speed I think.

```
f[M_Integer,k_Integer]:=Apply[#+Table[If[i <= M-Total[#],1,0],{i,1,k}]&,{Table[IntegerPart[M/k],{k}]}];

f[100,7]
{15,15,14,14,14,14,14}
```

The correction can be done in-line too...

```
f[M_Integer,k_Integer]:=Table[IntegerPart[M/k]+If[i <= M-k*IntegerPart[M/k],1,0],{i,1,k}];

f[100,7]
{15,15,14,14,14,14,14}
```

Marginally more compact...

```
f[M_Integer,k_Integer]:=Apply[Table[If[i<=M-k #,#+1,#],{i,1,k}]&,{IntegerPart[M/k]}];
```

Answer (score 4):

Using basic math:

```
f[m_, k_] := Floor[Table[m + i - 1, {i, k}] / k];
f[100, 7]

{14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15}
```

Comment: It is going to be slow but I like the compactness of the code. :)

Comment: Thanks @Kuba. I'm curious about what makes it slow (being a novice at Mathematica). Would it be notably faster with the operations inside the `Table`? I.e., `Table[Floor[(m + i - 1)/k], {i, k}]`

Comment: Very nice!  I feel foolish for not seeing this simple solution.  You could also write this `f = Quotient[# + Range@#2 - 1, #2] &` which is shorter and should also be faster.